# Automake configure script errors on Solaris with _ACEOF: cannot execute

Tags: solaris, configure, automake, libtool

I'm trying to run a configure script that I created using automake. It succeeds on OSs like Ubuntu, Redhat, and even AIX. But it fails to run on Solaris producing this error snippet.

```
configure: creating ./config.status
./configure[14670]: .[1]: _ACEOF: cannot execute [Not a directory]
configure: error: could not make ./config.status
```

Does anyone have ideas on why this error might be occurring on Solaris? Am I missing a dependency or a configure check that I need to account for with Solaris?

Comment: The problem might be at/around line 14670 in file `configure`. You might want to quote the relevant lines. Preferably with lines-numbers (cat -n)

Comment: What are you trying to configure?